# iOS 16 Beta 4 StoreKitUIService Crash

Tags: ios

Following the release of iOS 16 beta 4 on July 27, 2022, I've seen a spike in crash reports with the following stack trace:

```html
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Crashed: com.apple.UIKit._UIViewServiceInterfaceConnectionRequest com.apple.ios.StoreKitUIService
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39b8 objc_release_x8 + 16
1  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x3e2c bool HelperBase<GenericInline>::disposeCapture<(HelperBase<GenericInline>::BlockCaptureKind)3>(unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 68
2  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x2a98 HelperBase<GenericInline>::destroyBlock(Block_layout*, bool, unsigned char*) + 160
3  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x213c _call_dispose_helpers_excp + 72
4  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x1d54 _Block_release + 252
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x40fc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0xb7b4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
7  libdispatch.dylib              0xc300 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x16ec4 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread + 8
```

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue. It does appear to be Apple's bug to fix, so I've filed a report via Feedback Assistant. Posting here for visibility in case others are able to reproduce.